# OS X Usage Statistics: How to Find Daily Average Display On Time

Tags: macos, statistics, sleep, wakeup

### I'm looking to find the daily average amount of time I spend using my computer.

If my display is off, I'm not using my computer. If it's on, I am. (This is a good enough assumption for my purposes).

Using `pmset`, I can see this information but only for a couple of days:

`pmset -g log | grep "Display is turned on"`:

```
2016-03-12 11:19:08 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-12 12:47:41 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-12 16:00:11 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-12 17:47:43 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-12 18:56:27 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-12 19:47:26 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-12 20:34:56 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-12 21:20:48 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-12 23:08:32 -0500 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-13 10:59:28 -0400 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-13 11:39:30 -0400 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-13 12:56:20 -0400 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-13 13:27:17 -0400 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-13 16:18:58 -0400 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-13 16:23:40 -0400 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-13 16:35:28 -0400 Notification          Display is turned on
2016-03-13 16:59:29 -0400 Notification          Display is turned on
```

`pmset -g log | grep "Display is turned off"`:

```
2016-03-12 01:46:21 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-12 12:46:55 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-12 12:54:29 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-12 17:28:31 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-12 18:01:29 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-12 19:20:19 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-12 19:47:31 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-12 21:11:52 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-12 22:19:23 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-13 01:07:07 -0500 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-13 11:15:46 -0400 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-13 12:55:57 -0400 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-13 13:09:03 -0400 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-13 15:25:05 -0400 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-13 16:23:37 -0400 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-13 16:35:25 -0400 Notification          Display is turned off
2016-03-13 16:59:28 -0400 Notification          Display is turned off
```

**I need at least 30 days of data to get a solid average**. Does `pmset`'s log history even go back that far? Is there an easier way to obtain the data I'm looking for? If so, how?

Answer (score 1):

Ok, this is what I've discovered:

The last 15 days of `pmset`'s log files are located in `/var/log/powermanagement`.

---

*I figured this out by simply outputting the contents of the entire log to a
text file:*

```
pmset -g log > log.txt
```

*and it says on the first line of that file,* `PM ASL data store: /var/log/powermanagement`

---

Only the two most recent days are readable (the ones with just the `.asl` extension) while the other, older ones are gzipped (the ones with the `.asl.gz` extensions).

Simply unzipping the gzipped files will make them show up with `pmset -g log | grep "Display is turned on"` (or `"Display is turned off"`)

As mentioned above, it's still only 15 days. I have Time Machine backups but the `/var/log/powermanagement` directory is empty in all of them.